# Three dots under variable in proof?

Tags: calculus

What do the three dots mean under the variables in part (c) of the proof in the following picture?

[image]

Comment: Since you don't know exactly how to typeset it, a pic would be helpful to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: @MikePierce http://tinypic.com/r/2rfc5xh/9

Comment: I have never seen this before.  Perhaps it's best if you ask your instructor if you have one, or try to find an explanation in your book.

Answer (score 3):

I think that those dots are just there to indicate what has changed in each line. In the first line of (c), there are dots under the $a$s because the $a$ was added on both sides when you go from $b=a$ to $a\cdot b = a\cdot a$.

Comment: Well I don't think that was completely necessary but this sounds like he most logical explanation.

Comment: At first I thought the Q was about the dots in line (e).....